# building rpm creates /usr/lib/rpm/rpmrc, yet rpm executable requires /usr/local/lib/rpm/rpmrc

Tags: build, rpm, make-install

I have built `rpm` (Version 4.14.1) with the usual trilogy:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
make install
```

This went without error and the `rpm` executable was installed, as expected, into `/usr/bin/rpm`.

When I then tried to execute `rpm`, it wouldn't do anything and exit with `Unable to open /usr/local/lib/rpm/rpmrc for reading: No such file or directory.`.

When I then created a symbolic link `ln -s /usr/lib/rpm/rpmrc /usr/local/lib/rpm/rpmrc`, the executable `rpm` could be started.

Is this behaviour expected? Should `make install` not place the `rpmrc` file into a place where `rpm` finds it?

Comment: It sounds like you might have stomped on the `rpm` you already had on your system? RPM is designed to manage *all* packages on a box; I'm not sure what installing it this way would be expected to do for you.

Comment: Aaron, i was installing it this way because I have had no rpm on my system.